# Failed to render the markdown file relative to the larger size, causing the page to not open

Tags: docsify

### Bug report

##### Copy procedure

Normal installation procedure

##### Current behavior

This is a file of the same type

https://wiki.djxx.club/#/%E8%80%83%E7%A0%94/%E8%8B%B1%E8%AF%AD/%E5%86%99%E4%BD%9C/%E5%BA%94%E7%94%A8%E6%96%87/03

---

https://wiki.djxx.club/#/%E8%80%83%E7%A0%94/%E8%8B%B1%E8%AF%AD/%E5%86%99%E4%BD%9C/%E5%BA%94%E7%94%A8%E6%96%87/04

This file is too large to load.

The console will report errors, but none of them are relevant.

##### Expected behavior

Normal loading

##### For other information

- Docsify Version :4.13

Answer (score 0):

You can use `docsify.js` instead of `docsify.min.js` to see specific error messages.